# How to COUNT(*) in Slick 2.0?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

According to the [Slick 2.0 documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/queries.html), 
to get the count of rows in a table:

```
val q1 = coffees.length
// compiles to SQL (simplified):
//   select count(1) from "COFFEES"
```

However, it turns out that `coffees.length` is of type `Column[Int]`.

How does one execute the query and get the value?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I just had this same problem upgrading to slick 2.0.  I forget where the exact method lives, but the generic `.run` seems to work for me, i.e.

```
coffees.length.run
```

Comment: For some reason this `run` method is not available to me (could I be missing a trait on my DB driver?)... I was, however, able to get it to run like this: `scala.slick.lifted.Compiled(coffees.length).run`. If anyone knows what I'm missing to prevent the shorter version from working, let me know!

Comment: Amazing!, thank you!

@ChrisW : did you import your Driver profile simple?

Comment: @KrzysztofKowalski: I could have sworn I *did* have all the symbols from my driver's `simple` module imported, but in any case, for some reason the shorter syntax (`table.length.run`) *is* working now.

Comment: This works, but the performance can be really bad. See my comment to @tuxSlayer below.

Answer (score 5):

```
StaticQuery.queryNA[Int]("select count(*) from \"" + TableName + "\"").first
```

Quotes are needed if your table name is not upper case.

Comment: Note that this query can be an order of magnitude faster than the `.length.run` alternative. My test DB has about 180k rows, and on my computer the first approach takes about 350ms and the StaticQuery approach takes around 30ms, which is about the same I get from mysql console.

Comment: Yeah I query plan for ```coffees.length.run``` kinda query is horrible. So many nested queries: ```select x2.x3 from (select count(1) as x3 from (select x4.`updated_at` as x5, x4.`description` as x6, x4.`status` as x7) from `sales` x4) x19) x2```

Answer (score 1):

<del>Try `coffees.length.first` should execute and return `Int`</del>

Sorry, indeed, in the slick 1.0 there was first method to do this, in Slick 2.0 they get rid of it in favor of more generic `run`.

The function to execute query is

```
coffees.length.run
```

Comment: I had tried that earlier, but Column[Int] doesn't have a first method.